# WiFi doens't work

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I have replace widows by ubuntu but the wifi card are not detected. I can't connect to wifi network. Soemone can help me please ?

In the additional drivers windows, there is nothing.

The network controller: Intel Wireless 8265/8275.

Informations:

*sudo rfkill list all*:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth  
  Soft blocked: no  
  Hard blocked: no
```

*lspci*:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

Ubuntu version: 20.04

It's not a Dual Boot, there is only Ubuntu on the pc

*lspci -knn | grep Net -A3*:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:8110]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

*dmesg | grep iwl*

```
null
```

*dpkg -l | grep linux*

```
ii  console-setup-linux                           1.194ubuntu3                          all          Linux specific part of console-setup
ii  libselinux1:amd64                             3.0-1build2                           amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libv4l-0:amd64                                1.18.0-2build1                        amd64        Collection of video4linux support libraries
ii  libv4lconvert0:amd64                          1.18.0-2build1                        amd64        Video4linux frame format conversion library
ii  linux-base                                    4.5ubuntu3.1                          all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                                1.187.2                               all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic-hwe-20.04                       5.4.0.51.54                           amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-42                        5.4.0-42.46                           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic                5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-51                        5.4.0-51.56                           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-51-generic                5.4.0-51.56                           amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04               5.4.0.51.54                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic                  5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-51-generic                  5.4.0-51.56                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04                 5.4.0.51.54                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                          5.4.0-51.56                           amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic                5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-51-generic                5.4.0-51.56                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic          5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-51-generic          5.4.0-51.56                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-sound-base                              1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                  all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  pptp-linux                                    1.10.0-1build1                        amd64        Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) Client
ii  syslinux                                      3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2   amd64        collection of bootloaders (DOS FAT and NTFS bootloader)
ii  syslinux-common                               3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2   all          collection of bootloaders (common)
ii  syslinux-legacy                               2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu9                  amd64        Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS floppies
ii  util-linux                                    2.34-0.1ubuntu9                       amd64        miscellaneous system utilities
```

*grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/**

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:remove iwlwifi \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
```

Comment: check to see if your wifi is hard blocked
run the following command
rfkill list all if its blocked then note its id and use the following command rfkill unblock id replace id with id of your wireless controller In case the above does not help, would need the following info
Please provide information about the ubuntu version you are using and also specify the output of the command lspci

Comment: _sudo rfkill list all_ :
`0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
`
_lspci_: `02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
`
and ubuntu version: 20.04

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I have edit my post with informations.

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: @Pilot6 No, there is only linux on the pc

Comment: Then please add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: i have edit with the output

Comment: It looks like kernel is not fully installed. Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux`.

Comment: i have add `dpkg -l | grep linux`

Comment: All looks good except `iwlwifi` is not loading. Please add output of `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: done, i have edit